# Control Android phone by Python

Tags: android, python, usb

Android phone is connected to PC through USB, is there a way to connect wifi network using phython?

Phone should not be rooted, i know through adb if the phone is rooted we can connect. But I need a solution without the phone being rooted

Comment: Why do you want to do this via Python specifically? Could look at WiFiManager to do this in a traditional Java/Android application

Comment: Python is the text executor which will be running in PC, I am fine is creating an app with android. But the problem is how can I control the app from my PC through USB?. The app will contain wifi disable/enable, list of available networks and if we select one network it wil ask for password. How to do these operations from the PC?